# Ubuntu 18.04.1 black screen w/ cursor after login

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04

installed ubuntu and Steamplay because the hype is real. Only problem, in the middle of installing an extension for changing brightness (through store), the PC completely froze, and since, I get a black screen after logging in (unlike other questions in which it boots to a black screen), only with the cursor working. Have a GTX 1060, installed the proprietary drivers a few boots back.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)